# VBA for week number of a month similar to desktop calendar

Tags: excel, week-number, vba

Please could you assist me to add Week number for particular months?

This the vba:

```
With Target
If .Column <> 10 Or .Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
If .Value = "Select" Then
    If .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        .Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Now - 1      
    End If
```

My definition of week number is based on full weeks being Sunday through to Saturday:

1. If the first of the month does not start on a Sunday then any days up to the first Saturday of the month will be **Week 1**
2. The next sets of Sunday through Saturday will be **Week 2**, **Week 3**, **Week 4** etc. Unless the month started on a Sunday in which case the sets will be **Week 1**, **Week 2**, **Week 3** etc.
3. If the month does not end on a Saturday, then the Sunday through to till the end of the month will be **Week N+1** where **N** is the last full week given by step 2.

For example: this month, the 1st of March is on Wednesday. So March 1st-4th (Wed-Sat) will be 1 week and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and see if the [`WeekNum`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) function suits your purpose.

You can use it in your code like this:

`.Offset(0, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now - 1)`

The documentation says:

> Returns the week number of a specific date. For example, the week containing January 1 is the first week of the year, and is numbered week 1.
>
> There are two systems used for this function:
>
> System 1    The week containing January 1 is the first week of the year, and is numbered week 1.
>
> System 2    The week containing the first Thursday of the year is the first week of the year, and is numbered as week 1. This system is the methodology specified in ISO 8601, which is commonly known as the European week numbering system.

### Edit

OP definition of week is per a desktop calendar where each green block is a week - so March 2017 has 5 weeks. Note January 2016 has six weeks under this system!

[image]

Therefore, the [`WeekNum`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) formula will not give the expected result. Instead the following function can be used:

```
Function GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek(dt As Date) As String

    Dim lngDayOfMonth As Long
    Dim lngWeekDay As Long
    Dim dtFirstDayOfMonth As Date
    Dim lngFactor As Long

    lngDayOfMonth = Day(dt)
    lngWeekDay = Weekday(dt, vbSunday) '<~~ Sunday=1, Monday=2, etc
    
    'does month start on Sunday?
    dtFirstDayOfMonth = DateValue("01-" & Month(dt) & "-" & Year(dt))
    If Weekday(dtFirstDayOfMonth, vbSunday) = 1 Then
        lngFactor = 1
    Else
        lngFactor = 2
    End If
    
    'get calendar week number for date
    GetCalendarTypeMonthWeek = "Week " & CStr(Int((lngDayOfMonth - lngWeekDay) / 7) + lngFactor)

End Function
```

To be used in the sample code like:

`.Offset(0, 2).Value = GetMonthWeek(Now - 1)`

Comment: ok, but i need the week number from Wk1 to Wk4 for every month.

Comment: Apart from February in a non-leap year, months have 4 weeks and a few extra days. How would you handle January 29 - 31 for example? Perhaps you can update your question with your definition of week number please.

Comment: True but as you said even if it is going to be on day in a week, it will be considered as WK4 or WK5 depending on the number of weeks in a month.

Comment: So your definition is first 7 days = week 1, second 7 days = week 2, third 7 days= week 3, fourth 7 days = week 4; and any remaining days = week 5 ?

Comment: So if March 1st was a Tuesday then week 1 is March 1st to March 5th (the Saturday) then that would be Week 1 comprising of 5 days?

Comment: Not necessarily, Example: this month-1st of March is on Wednesday. So 1-4 (Wed-Sat) will be 1 week and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think the next function will return the value you want:

```
Function WeekOfTheMonth(DateRef As Date) As Integer
    Dim WeekFirstDayRefMonth As Integer
    WeekFirstDayRefMonth = Application.WeekNum(DateSerial(Year(DateRef), Month(DateRef), 1), 2)
    Dim WeekLastDayRefMonthB As Integer        
    WeekLastDayRefMonthB = Application.WeekNum(DateSerial(Year(DateRef), Month(DateRef), 1) - 1, 2)
    Select Case WeekFirstDayRefMonth - WeekLastDayRefMonthB
        Case 0: WeekOfTheMonth = Application.WeekNum(DateRef, 2) - WeekLastDayRefMonthB + 1
        Case 1: WeekOfTheMonth = Application.WeekNum(DateRef, 2) - WeekLastDayRefMonthB
        Case Else: WeekOfTheMonth = Application.WeekNum(DateRef, 2)
    End Select
End Function
```

Just write `WeekOfTheMonth("place your date here")` on your code and you're good to go.
Please note: I didn't check all the scenarios for this code so please let me know if you're getting unexpected results.